# Wordpress: can't add a plugins_loaded hook from functions.php?

Tags: wordpress

My `functions.php` includes this code:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'plugin_overrides');
function plugin_overrides() {
   error_log("B", 0);
}
```

And I've modified `wp-settings.php` to put debug calls around the hook stuff:

```
error_log("A", 0);
do_action( 'plugins_loaded' );
error_log("C", 0);
```

The idea is to replace a couple of woocommerce hook actions with my own, so my `plugin_overrides` calls `remove_hook`, and so on.

However, `plugin_overrides` doesn't seem to be called. When I reload any page on my site the error log only shows the `A` and `C` messages, and never `B`. And, in fact, `wp-settings.php` is actually run twice, for some reason - I get 2 sets of `A/C` messages. Except when I load a woocommerce-specific page, when it's run *3* times, with my woocommerce-specific `add_action` debug messages appearing after the first call.

Any idea what's going on? How do I hook into `plugins_loaded` to call `remove_action` for plugins?

Comment: The answer seems to be to hook on `wp_loaded`, since the `functions.php` code is run too late.

Comment: ...but this messes up the admin page, so isn't the right answer.

Comment: i think this might clearify a little bit though im not entirerly sure.. Probably has to do with the `plugins_loaded` hook being call earlier on. Hense your statement in `functions.php` has no effect. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence

Comment: very interesting issue though im gonna do some testing on my side see if i can come up with something.